# What is the difference between split -C and split -b?

Tags: command-line, arguments, split

According to the man page:

```
-b, --bytes=SIZE
put SIZE bytes per output file

-C, --line-bytes=SIZE
put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
```

So if `-b` already splits a file by bytes per file, what is the purpose of `-C`? How is it any different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-C` attempts to put complete lines of output into the target file, up to a maximum size of SIZE, whereas `-b` just counts bytes without regards to line endings.  `-C` may put less output into the output file in order to stop at the closest line ending that doesn't put it over size.

Comment: So `-C` is like: "Give me complete lines, but do not exceed SIZE", and `-b` is like: "I want exactly SIZE unless there isn't anything left". Is that right?

Comment: That's it in a nutshell.  Much more succinctly explained than my answer. :)